# How do you resolve 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement'?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

So I have created a database and want to insert information from my form in VB to the database. I have linked and coded it however, I keep getting this error message: **Syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement** . I have looked at many other similar questions however none of the solutions work. Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Class Form1
Dim Provider As String
Dim DataFile As String
Dim ConnString As String
Dim MyConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= "
    DataFile = "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DatabaseTest\DatabaseTest\Database.accdb"
    ConnString = Provider & DataFile
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
    MyConnection.Open()
    Dim Strng As String
    Strng = "INSERT INTO [Table1]([StudentName], [StudentScore] Values (?,?))"
    Dim Cmmnd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Strng, MyConnection)
    Cmmnd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("StudentName", CType(txtName.Text, String)))
    Cmmnd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("StudentScore", CType(txtScore.Text, String)))
    Try
        Cmmnd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Cmmnd.Dispose()
        MyConnection.Close()
        txtName.Clear()
        txtScore.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: `"INSERT INTO [Table1]([StudentName], [StudentScore]) Values (?,?)"` -  end brace in wrong place.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to coding :/ What is an end brace?

Comment: `)` did you see my example?

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's working now!!

Answer (score 4):

End brace in the wrong place. You also do not need to convert the Text property to a string in the parameters.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Class Form1
  Dim Provider As String
  Dim DataFile As String
  Dim ConnString As String
  Dim MyConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
      Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= "
      DataFile = "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DatabaseTest\DatabaseTest\Database.accdb"
      ConnString = Provider & DataFile
      MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
      MyConnection.Open()
      Dim Strng As String
      Strng = "INSERT INTO [Table1]([StudentName], [StudentScore]) Values (?,?)"
      Dim Cmmnd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Strng, MyConnection)
      Cmmnd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("StudentName", txtName.Text))
      Cmmnd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("StudentScore", txtScore.Text))
     Try
       Cmmnd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       Cmmnd.Dispose()
       MyConnection.Close()
       txtName.Clear()
       txtScore.Clear()
     Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox(ex.Message)
     End Try
  End Sub
End Class
```